# allocate and deallocate memory in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to figure it out why this code doesn't work as it should. I would like to allocate memory for a dictionary file with over 250,000 words. Memory allocation works OK. However free memory doesn't. And, honestly I don't know why. It breaks during deallocation. Below is the code.
Thank you.

```
    #include <iostream>   // For general IO
    #include <fstream>    // For file input and output
    #include <cassert>    // For the assert statement
    using namespace std;

    const int NumberOfWords = 500000;   // Number of dictionary words
                 //if i change to == to exact number of words also doesnt work 
    const int WordLength = 17;      // Max word size + 1 for null 

    void allocateArray(char ** & matrix){
         matrix = new char*[NumberOfWords];

         for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfWords; i++) {
             matrix[i] = new char[WordLength];

               // just to be safe, initialize C-string to all null characters 
               for (int j = 0; j < WordLength; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = NULL;
               }//end for (int j=0...
         }//end for (int i...
    }//end allocateArray()

    void deallocateArray(char ** & matrix){
          // Deallocate dynamically allocated space for the array
          for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfWords; i++) {
                delete[] matrix[i];
          }
          delete[] matrix; // delete the array at the outermost level
    }

    int main(){
    char ** dictionary;

    // allocate memory
    allocateArray(dictionary);

    // Now read the words from the dictionary
    ifstream inStream;  // declare an input stream for my use
    int wordRow = 0;    // Row for the current word
    inStream.open("dictionary.txt");
    assert(!inStream.fail());  // make sure file open was OK

    // Keep repeating while input from the file yields a word
    while (inStream >> dictionary[wordRow]) {
        wordRow++;
    }
    cout << wordRow << " words were read in." << endl;

    cout << "Enter an array index number from which to display a word: ";
    long index;
    cin >> index;
    // Display the word at that memory address 
    cout << dictionary[index] << endl;

    deallocateArray(dictionary);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What 'breaks' mean? It crashes, or does not compile, which error message does it provide?

Comment: Also, consider replacing `for (int j = 0; j < WordLength; j++)` loop with `memset`

Comment: @DenisSheremet just stop and cmd window in VS will not close.

Comment: try use `std::vector<std::string>>`. You don't need to worry about allocation and deallocation.

Comment: @Art try adding some debug message to the loop, or simply run your program in debugger

Comment: @CrazyEddie I wear gray socks, and this information is as unnecessary here as yours

Comment: change `new char[WordLength]` to `new char[WordLength+1]`.

Comment: @barakmanos thanks for suggestion but didn't work.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: For a real [mcve], you shouldn't need to read from an external file.  You should be able to add sufficient entries in the code.

Comment: Also I don't see anywhere where you protect against input words longer than `WordLength-1`.  If you don't do so, you'll likely see errors when you run this under Valgrind, and that should indicate your problem.  You *have* run it under Valgrind, right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the following line:

```
 while (inStream >> dictionary[wordRow]) {
```

There is no limit on the input line length and the application overwrites at least one of string buffers. I would fix it this way:

```
 while (inStream >> std::setw(WordLength - 1) >> dictionary[wordRow]) {
```

Please do not forget to add

```
 #include <iomanip>
```

with `setd::setw` declaration

Comment: Your suggestion worked partially. The console closed at the end. But,after  this change program displayed 7,000 more words. (words in file 263,000 after change 270,000).

Comment: What do you mean by `console closed at the end`?

Comment: I mean program reached "return 0;" in main ();

Comment: It means that the application read everything. I think the issue is that application reads several words (as you see them) as one. I would rewrite the reading part to be sure that both you and the application used the same meaning of `word`.

Comment: The reason it reads more words now is because words that would have been too long before this change (and caused the undefined behavior due to buffer overruns) are now being read as two (or more) words. If a word is longer than 16 characters the original code would have undefined behavior. After the modification the code will read the first 16 characters as one word and the remaining characters as another word. If you read the words into std::string objects instead of fixed size buffers both problems will be solved.